# How to insert float values in to a map in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

i need to insert 3 values into a map of type `std::map<int,std::pair<float,float> >`.
so that map will have data as { `22  32626.23  53232.63` }

```
std::map<int,std::pair<float,float> > my_MainMap;
std::map<float,float>  myMap1;
int iValue;
float fValue1, fValue2;
```

I have tried 3 different methods for inserting values:
Method 1:

```
myMap1.insert(std::pair<float, float>(fValue1, fValue2));
m_Mainmap.insert(std::pair<int,std::pair<float,float> >(iValue,myMap1 ));
```

Method 2:

```
m_Mainmap.insert(std::pair<int,std::pair<float,float>>::value_type(iValue,fValue1, fValue2));
```

Method 3:

```
myMap1.insert(std::pair<float, float>(fValue1, fValue2));
m_Mainmap.insert(std::make_pair(iValue,myMap1 ));
```

The code I have written is not compiling. Where am I wrong?

```
In constructor 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&) [with _U1 = int, _U2 = std::map<float, float>, _T1 = const int, _T2 = std::pair<float, float>]':
 error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<float, float>::pair(const std::map<float, float>&)'
```

Comment: `myMap1` is not a `std::pair` (but a `std::map`) so can't be used as value for `my_MainMap`

Comment: `my_MainMap[some_int_value] = std::pair<float,flota>(float_value_1, float_value_2)`

Comment: Look, he has hidden the answer in the last code block of the question :D
Compiler messages are worth to read ;)

Comment: @user3021982 It is not clear what you are trying to insert. Whether you are trying to insert all elements of one map into another map or only one element of one map into another map. How the element(s) are selected? What is the value of variable I?

Comment: as mentioned, you are inserting a `map` as the second argument, instead of a `pair`. Something like `mymap.insert(std::make_pair(i, std::make_pair(f1, f2)))` should work.

Comment: I guess what you really want is: `std::vector<std::pair<float,float>>` using map with float key is not very good idea, since floating point comparisons are not so accurate.

Comment: @SHR If he wants to use floats as a key, how is using a non-associative data structure going to help?

Comment: Note that using `float` or `double` as keys into a single-valued `map` or `set` is code smell: often a sign of a bug just lurking, waiting to strike.  Two seemingly identical calculations can lead to slightly different `float` or `double` values in practice.  You'll want to use a multimap, and query for existence & get values using epsilons.  You may also want a comparison function that supports `NaN` without destroying your map/set.

Comment: `my_MainMap[22] = make_pair( 32626.23f, 53232.63f );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 is almost there. You need to take into account the fact you have nested a pair.

```
m_Mainmap.insert(std::pair<int, std::pair<float,float>>(i, std::pair<float,float>(fOuterRadius,fInnerRadius)));
```

Or

```
m_Mainmap.insert(std::make_pair(i, std::make_pair(fOuterRadius,fInnerRadius)));
```

So long as you know the differences between the insert function and this operator, also consider the following. (Insert doesn't update the value if the key already existed)

```
m_Mainmap[i] = std::pair<float,float>(fOuterRadius,fInnerRadius);
```

I don't know what your `std::map<float,float>` is for, as you never elaborate on it in your problem statement.